# unittest in python not working as expected

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

We are deploying the code in `CI/CD` fashion via `Terraform`. So, we have a `lambda` `function` under which I have written a code for retrieving the specific `secret` creds.

Below is my lambda code:

```
logger = get_provisioner_logger()
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(
    service_name="secretsmanager",
    region_name=""
)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("lambda invoked with event: " + str(event))
    domain_name = "db-creds"
    secret_data = getCredentials(domain_name)
    acc = secret_data["acc"]
    user = secret_data["user"]
    password = secret_data["pass"]
    #....
    #here we are invoking other methods where we are passing the above creds
    #....
    return handler.handle(event)


def getCredentials(domain_name):
    try:
        response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=domain_name)
        result = json.loads(response['SecretString'])
        print(result)
        logger.info("Got value for secret %s.", domain_name)
        return result
    except UnableToRetrieveDetails as e:
        logger.error("unable to retrieve secret details due to ", str(e))
        raise e
```

Now, I have written a test case where I am trying to mock the client and trying to fake the return value of the response but am unable to do so. Below is my code:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from api.lambda_handler import getCredentials
import json

@patch('api.lambda_handler.client')
class TestSecretManagerMethod(TestCase):

    def test_get_secret_creds(self, sm):
        sm.response.return_value = {"secret":"gotsomecreds"}
        actual = getCredentials("db-creds")
        self.assertEqual(actual, "hey")
```

It gives me below error:

```
 raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not MagicMock.
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74874345/6485881) is on the right track.

The problem is that you're mixing up what needs to be patched and returned.

In your code you're saying: If you call `client.response()` then return `{"secret":"gotsomecreds"}`. The problem is that this is not what's happening in your code.

You're actually calling `client.get_secret_value(something)` and that's what needs to be patched:

```py
@patch('api.lambda_handler.client')
class TestSecretManagerMethod(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_secret_creds(self, sm):
        sm.get_secret_value.return_value = {
            "SecretString": '{"secret": "gotsomecreds"}',
        }
        actual = getCredentials("db-creds")
        self.assertEqual(actual, {"secret": "gotsomecreds"})
```

I also took the liberty of fixing the assertion, because the way you set it up `"hey"` won't be returned.

As an aside, I highly recommend you check out the [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) project. It provides mocks around most of the AWS API and will save you a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah, the `hey` was passed in order to ensure that I get the actual result at least. I knew it will fail because the actual won't match the expected. But yeah I got it where I went wrong. Thanks a lot, @Maurice.